# How can I make the keyboard disappear after entering the text?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have two text fields in my view. I did it using IB. My problems are

1. After entering the text in textField1 I am entering text in textField2. When I click in    textField1 again the previous text is disappeared in the textField1.
2. After entering the text in both the textFields, I need the keyboard to disappear. But, even I touched the return key in the keyboard layout or I touched the screen outside the text field the keyboard is not disappearing.

How can I make this.
Thank you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    self.title = @"Edit";
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(save)];

    //[nameField becomeFirstResponder];
    nameField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO; //First text field
    [nameField resignFirstResponder];
    //[descriptionField becomeFirstResponder];
    descriptionField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO; //second text dield
    [descriptionField resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}   

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == nameField) {
    [nameField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if(textField == descriptionField){
    [descriptionField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I did in the above way but the keyboard is still not disappearing. And after entering the text in textField1 when I press return key the cursor is not going to textField2. How can I make it work ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1, check the `clearsOnBeginEditing` property of the text field.

For problem 2, you can send the `resignFirstResponder` message to the text field.

See [Managing Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW50) section in the [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result. First thing in my mistake is I did not add  UITextFieldDelegate in interface. And the remaining I did the changes in code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.title = @"Edit";
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(save)];

    [nameField becomeFirstResponder];
    nameField.delegate = self;
    descriptionField.delegate = self;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSLog(@"Return Key Pressed");
    if (textField == nameField) {
        [nameField resignFirstResponder];
        [descriptionField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if(textField == descriptionField){
    [descriptionField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

After entering the text in textField1 if I touch return the cursor goes to textFeild2. It is working good. But when I touch the screen out of text field the keyboard is not disappearing.
Thank you.